# AAPT: error: unexpected element <intent-filter> found in <manifest><application>

Tags: intentfilter, android-studio-4.0

I tried an android application code from github. When I open this project in my Android Studio, and build the project in my phone, it fails and gives error for AndroidManifest.xml on using intent-filter in line 45. I've tried the solutions given previously in stackoverflow by closing the activity tag but it ended up in more errors.

Here is my manifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ravneet.cameratester">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SignInActivityWithDrive"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_in"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
            android:value="id=AIzaSyCPeewJFbuOGwUFz-rIsjTQTXIPvc5jiyM" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.DRIVE_OPEN" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.AIzaSyCPeewJFbuOGwUFz-rIsjTQTXIPvc5jiyM" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/png" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpeg" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/jpg" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity
            android:name=".DriveSaveActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drive_save"
            android:parentActivityName=".SignInActivityWithDrive"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.ravneet.cameratester.SignInActivityWithDrive" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ImageDisplayActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_image_display"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".BillDisplayActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bill_display"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks.